# Sending an SFML Image to OpenCL

Tags: opencl, sfml

I'm trying to send an SFML Image to OpenCL. But I only get corrupted data back. My guess is that I handle the pixelData wrong, but I don't know how to do it correctly :/

```
void ImageWindow::xBlend() 
{
    size_t size = sizeof(cl_uchar4) * textureSize.x * textureSize.y;

    cl::Buffer bufferIn(manager->context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, size);
    cl::Buffer bufferOut(manager->context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, size);

    auto pixelData = (cl_uchar4*)image.getPixelsPtr();

    manager->queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(bufferIn, CL_TRUE, 0, size, pixelData);
    functorXBlend(bufferIn, bufferOut);

    manager->queue.enqueueReadBuffer(bufferOut, CL_TRUE, 0, size, pixelData);
    newTexture.update(image);
}
```

Comment: You'll need to be more specific what you mean with "corrupted data". Are you sure the size is calculated correctly?

Comment: My guess is that the problem is not in the "sending" or "receiving", as you state. But in the `functorxBlend`, are the data in the format the function expects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error myself. Most stupid mistake ever. The above code is correct, the problem was that I messed up the local worksize.

```
functorXBlend = cl::KernelFunctor(
    cl::Kernel(manager->program, "xBlend"), 
    manager->queue, cl::NullRange, 
    cl::NDRange(textureSize.x, textureSize.y), 
    cl::NullRange);
```

Instead I had this:

```
functorXBlend = cl::KernelFunctor(
    cl::Kernel(manager->program, "xBlend"), 
    manager->queue, cl::NullRange, 
    cl::NDRange(textureSize.x, textureSize.y), 
    cl::NDRange(textureSize.x, textureSize.y));
```

Comment: If the number of pixels in your texture exceeds the maximum size of a workgroup (which can be small, like 128 or 256), that won't work either. Just leave the work group size `cl::NullRange` and the driver will select a size for you.